# Ruby Code to add a Timestamp to each file in a particular directory

Tags: ruby

I have a directory named "MyDir". I m using Ubuntu OS. And I have 7 files with various extensions. I want to write a Ruby Program to add a Timestamp to each of the file.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I have tried to open the files & added Timestamp = Time.now.to_i but it didnt worked

Comment: Post the code you have tried so far directly in your question, doing so will help others identify what you are doing wrong (and also what you are trying to do).

Comment: -1 for a poorly-specified question. In the future, please describe more clearly not only what you have, but what you want in the end, what code you have tried, what the result (or error) was with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to get a listing of all the files in the target directory (see [`Dir.glob(...)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob)) and then open the file for writing in "[append mode](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html)" (see [`File.open(...)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-open)) and simply write in the timestamp.  For example:

```ruby
def add_timestamps(dir, timestamp=Time.now)
  Dir[File.join(dir, '*')].each do |filename|
    File.open(filename, 'a') { |f| f.puts(timestamp) }
  end
end

add_timestamps('MyDir') # OR...
add_timestamps('MyDir', Time.parse('2001-02-03T04:05:06Z'))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add it to the file name

```
t = Time.new.to_i; Dir["MyDir/*"].each { |x| File.rename(x,"#{x}.#{t}") }
# or dont add timestamp on files that are ending with 10 digits
t = Time.new.to_i; Dir["MyDir/*"].each { |x| File.rename(x,"#{x}.#{t}") unless /\.\d{10}$/.match(x) }

#if you want to add it to the end of the file's content
t = Time.new.to_i; Dir["MyDir/*"].each { |x| File.open(x,'a') { |f| f.write("\n#{t}\n") } }
```

Comment: Thanks ! It is renaming my files with some numbers but inside that file nothing is written

Comment: @RoRProg..was there content inside the files before?

Comment: No They are empty files. I just want to add the timestamp inside it. So that when i open those files i should see the time date etc printed inside it.